# What does format "yMeBg" mean in nvm set-colors command, is the letters in the format string stand for something or just meaningless

Tags: node.js, bash, nvm

NVM document shows that `nvm set-colors` command set colors using format **"yMeBg"**,
I am confused with it, is the letter in the format string stand for something or just meaningless? Since I know DateTime format string like "yyyy-MM-dd" ,the letter stand for year ,month, or date.

Answer (score 0):

it is used to colour code the node and dependency versions.

- y: The "y" character represents the version number.
- M: The "M" character represents the current active version.
- e: The "e" character represents the arrow symbol indicating the current version.
- B: The "B" character represents the color for displaying the branch information (when using nvm with Git).
- g: The "g" character represents the color for displaying the name of the installed Node.js version.

hence $ nvm set-colors MygRC

[image]